# Redirecting to route from Node.JS server doesn't render the next page

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redirect

Hi I have a react component that renders a form like this:

```
<form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
  <!-- a bunch of inputs here -->
</form>
```

where the function `onSubmit()` makes a post request to `/results` using axios:

```
handleSubmit(e) {
    var self = this;
    e.preventDefault();
    const {value1, value 2, ....} = this.state;
    axios.post('/results', {
        key1 : value1,
        key2 : value2,
        etc.
    }).then(function(response) {
      if (errors) {
          self.setState({errors: response.data.errorMessage});
      } 
    }).catch(function(error){
      console.log(error);
    });
  }
```

I have a route handler for the post request in my `server.js` which inserts the data from the form into a database. If there are errors then it'll send that data back to the client, otherwise it should redirect to the results page. The handler looks like this:

```
app.post('/results', function(req, res, next) {
  const reportExists = Report.findOne({
    attributes: ['caseId'],
    where: {caseId : req.body.caseId},
  }).then(report => {
    if (report) {
      console.log("report already exists");
      res.status(200).send({errorMessage : "Report has been submitted for this case id"});
    } else {
      const report = Report.create(
        {
          // data from form
        }
      ).then(() => {
        console.log('Record inserted successfully');
        var caseId = req.body.caseId;
        res.redirect("/results/" + caseId);
        next();
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log('failed to insert record');
        res.status(200).send({errorMessage: "Failed to insert record"});
      });
    }
  });
});
```

I have another `app.get('/results/:caseId')` handler which should render the appropriate route for the results page. But when the record is inserted successfully it doesn't redirect to that page, it stays on the same page as the form. My question is, should I be redirecting to that page from the client or the server?

Comment: Don't call `next()` after `res.redirect()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Submitting an Ajax call via client-side Javascript just gets the response back from the server, whatever it is.  A redirect is not automatically processed by the browser, it's just the ajax response to your javascript.   It is up to your client-side Javascript to decide what to do with the redirect response.

You have a couple choices.  You could detect the redirect response in your client-side Javascript and then set `window.location` with the new location and manually tell the browser to go to the new page.  Or, you could let the browser submit the form rather than your client-side Javascript and then the browser will follow the redirect response automatically.

---

Also, you should not be calling `next()` after you call `res.redirect()`.  Once you've sent the response, you should not enable other route handlers to execute.