# res.redirect in express returns the html source code & not just the URL

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, redirect, request

I'm trying to redirect a user to a login page when they click a button but instead of a redirect I get html source code and nothing happens.

Here's my redirect method in express:

```
function redirect(req, res) {
    res.redirect("https://dev-krbec.authentication.eu10.hana.ondemand.com/login");
};
```

Here's how it's called from the client with a simple get query:

```
$.get({
                url: document.URL + "api/redirect",
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    // window.location.href=data;
                },
                error: function (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                }
            });
```

However, the redirect is never performed and I only get a data variable with the whole html source code of page I want to redirect to.

This is how the query looks:
[image]

This is a response that should contain just the URL but it contains html source code instead:
[image]

Am I missing something?

Comment: An ajax call from the browser does absolutely nothing with a redirect response.  It just receives the 302 and the headers and it's entirely up to your ajax code to do something useful with the 302 response.

Comment: Thanks for a response but could you explain a little bit more how to redirect directly using res.redirect when I click some button for example? How to be really let's say moved into another page?

Comment: See [How to redirect with ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41078641/how-to-properly-redirect-in-nodejs-expressjs/41078774#41078774) and [Redirecting doesn't render desired page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45747563/redirecting-to-route-from-node-js-server-doesnt-render-the-next-page/45748133#45748133)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do and how your application is setup. Do you just want to return the url to set as the location.href? Instead of doing that, you could simply do the redirect on the client like so:

```
window.location.href = 'https://dev-krbec.authentication.eu10.hana.ondemand.com/login'
```

If you really just want to return the URL from the server, you could update your express route logic to return the url as a property on the response object:

```
function redirect(req, res) {
    res.send({url: "https://dev-krbec.authentication.eu10.hana.ondemand.com/login"});
};
```

My guess though, is that what you're really after is a true redirect from the server side with Express itself. If so, please post the route handler you have defined for the request vs. the function it may be calling. That may better allow us to see what may be wrong.